# issue with links, getting message 'ie.css isn't precompiled'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

I'm trying to fix my links at:

```
http://92.51.243.6/
```

Don't know why they don't work. The links I'm talking about are 'Home' and 'About' at the top of the page. It all works fine in local WEBrick mode. I heard Ajax could be the issue, so I took out the :remote=> true from those links, and disabled the ajax in a file scripts.js, that takes care of my ajax.

The code in the links is:

```
    <div id = "menu">
      <ul id = "home_page_links">
        <li><%= link_to "Home",about_us_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "About Us",about_us_path  %></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

In my routes.rb file I have:

```
QuestionnaireSite::Application.routes.draw do

  get "home", :to => "static_pages#about_us"
  get "about_us", :to => "static_pages#about_us"
```

The message I get, 'We're sorry, but something went wrong' is an error page from my public folder.

When I run:

```
tail -f /var/www/apps/myapp/current/log/production.log
```

I get:

```
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 87.198.119.247 at Thu May 30 10:52:04 +0100 2013
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered users/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/devise (4.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_fb_init.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_signed_out_header.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 7.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started GET "/about_us" for 87.198.119.247 at Thu May 30 11:02:29 +0100 2013
Processing by StaticPagesController#about_us as HTML
  Rendered static_pages/about_us.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms

ActionView::Template::Error (ie.css isn't precompiled):
    12:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    13:   <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    14:   <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    15:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'ie', :media => 'all' %>
    16:     <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    17:   <![endif]-->
    18: </head>
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:15:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1658874457_26880020'
```

So I'm getting an error: ie.css isn't precompiled.

Is there something I need to change in line 12 to 18, as per my error message?
I did do:

```
rake assets:precompile
```

which seems to have been done successfully as I got:

```
/home/app/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/bin/ruby /home/app/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: You can add the following line in your config file which passes an array config.assets.precompile += ['your.js', 'your.css'] as you have only one css that is giving you an issue so you can add that from the manifest. (ref - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets)

Answer (score 1):

I assume, the ie.css is in `lib/assets/stylesheets` or `vendor/assets/stylesheets`.
To include it in precompile, add in `config/environments/production.rb`

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( ie.css )
```

you say, `ie.css.scss` is in `app/assets/stylesheets`.
I assume that your `application.css` contains:

```
 *= require_tree .
```

then `ie.css.scss` is compiled, minified and included in your production `application.css` and there is no longer a conditional loading!

Your conditional

```
14:   <!--[if lt IE 9]>
15:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'ie', :media => 'all' %>
16:     <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
17:   <![endif]-->
```

tries to load it a second time.
Try to delete the `stylesheet_link_tag` and only keep the conditional script.

If you really need the css to be conditionally loaded, move it to `lib/assest/sytlesheet` so it is not included in `application.css` and add it to `assets.precompile` as mentioned above.

Comment: In fact, both those folders are empty. The ie.css.scss, and others, are in app/assets/stylesheets. Is that a problem? All the other stylesheet files seem to deploy ok, just not the ie.css one. Should I go ahead and add config.assets.precompile += %w( ie.css ) to production.rb and then push it to server? Thanks.

Comment: In fact, my application.css.scss has no *= require_tree. Lots of other stuff, but not that. But I have lots of other css.scss files in that folder and they seem to work ok. I will add it to my application.css file , redeploy and let you know how I get on. Need to go out for a few hours first though. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Martin M and others, I solved my problem.

basically the nub of the problem was exactly that, the error I was getting:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (ie.css isn't precompiled):
```

For a start, I didn't have *= require ie in my application.css.scss file, so I put it in. I have 8 or 9 scss files and the ie reference was missing, for some reason (I inherited this project from someone else).

Then I got rid of the code altogether, in my application.html.erb:

```
  <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <%#= stylesheet_link_tag 'ie', :media => 'all' %>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
```

I saved it all, pushed it up to master branch on github, then from there onto production branch and deployed it with:

```
cap production deploy:migrations
```

It's working now (other problems afterwards, but at least that part is working!)